# Django @csrf_exempt a logging endpoint

Tags: django, security, csrf, django-csrf

I'm making a social media site where users click into posts, and every time they do so, I call an endpoint to log a view for that post. Would it be safe to csrf_exempt this endpoint that only fetches a Post object from a slug and increases the post's view_count by 1?

Comment: Using `@csrf_exempt` for a `post` request is not an idea as this can make your application vulnerable to `Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)` attacks. I would suggest you to use Django signals to achieve this. When a post is viewed, you can send out a signal, and then use a different function to handle this signal and increase the post's view count.